# query with date in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Following is MY SAMPLE TABLE

```
create table mytable ( id int ,name text);

insert into mytable values(1,'tom');

insert into mytable values(2,'jerry');

select * from mytable;
```

Result...

```
  ID Name
  1  tom
  2  jerry
```

my expected result..

```
  ID Name
  1  tom_01_10_2014
  2  jerry_01_10_2014
```

Comment: Uh... and what would the date be based on?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something: `select id, name||to_char(current_date, '_dd_mm_yyyy') as name from mytable;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id,name||'_'||to_char(now()::date,'dd_mm_yyyy')  dated_name from mytable
```

---

[to_char()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html), [now()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html)